# Object doesn't support this property or method IE8 Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the error "Object doesn't support this property or method" in Explorer 8, this is the piece of code, I can't see the problem.

```
jQuery('.block_right h3').click(function(){

    jQuery(this).parent().find(".respuesta").slideToggle('slow').find(".block_right h3 span").toogle();

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.toogle` is probably a misspelling of `.toggle`

Comment: also, your second animation - on `.find(".block_right h3 span")` will only work if it is a child node of `jQuery(this).parent().find(".respuesta")`